# How to dynamically present an on the fly zipfile to users

Tags: php, zip

I'm editing an ancient script that zips several images and presents them dynamically to the user.

I have rewritten almost all of the code, but I can't find a way to way to output the contents of the zipfile. Writing it to the server is very undesirable.

I create the file with:

```
$z = new ZipArchive();
```

I can add content with:

```
$z->addFromString("filename",$string);
```

And I want to present it dynamically with:

```
header("Content-Type: application/zip;");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.zip;");

// I need a function to read the contents of the zipfile here. Something like:
echo $z->filecontent();
```

I can't find out what function to use for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would open the file, creating it most likely with temp name. Something like this:

```
$name = tempnam('/tmp','zip');
$z->open($name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)
```

After you finish adding all your files, you would close it.

```
$z->close();
```

Now when you are ready to send the data you would do this:

```
readfile($name);
```

After you are done, you want to clean up the temp file with:

```
unlink($name);
```

Comment: Great, that worked. The previous script used a method similar to what I described, so I was looking in the wrong direction

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation, look at the [close()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.close.php) method to actually save the file physically to the filesystem. Then you can use [readfile()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) on the saved file